# Como autorizar usuarios locales en aplicacion MVC

Tags: c#, mvc, razor, visual-studio-2017

Tengo una aplicacion en MVC la cual tiene un login.cshtml y este requiere autenticarse.

Esta pagina de login verifica al usuario y su contraseña las cuales existen en un archivo local en la aplicacion, este archivo es xml (contraseña encriptada)

Cuando uso el atributo `[Athorize]` en mi ActionResult, este no reconoce mi usuario el cual deberia dejarlo pasar.

Como puedo hacer esto? mi objetivo es bloquear el acceso a todas las paginas y solo que tengan que pasar por el login primero.

Cuando uso `[Authorize (Users= "administrator")]` este no funciona ya que no reconoce a mi usuario que se llama administrador.

Gracias,

Comment: Esta pregunta ya la habías realizado anteriormente, lo ideal sería que si ninguna de las dos respuestas en esa pregunta satisface tu problemática, hagas los ajustes necesarios a tu pregunta y hagas saber las personas que respondieron el por qué esa solución no es válida ;)

Comment: @Flxtr tienes toda la razon, me disculpo por haber posteado esta pregunta nuevamente. Voy a agregar comentarios en la pregunta original

Comment: Yo puse una respuesta en la pregunta original, si tienes alguna duda o algo no queda claro escríbeme por allá y lo revisamos ;)

Comment: @Flxtr si gracias!! ya acabo de agregar una respuesta a tu solucion